# How to add to PATH in a bash-like shell and OS agnostic way?

Tags: linux, macos

When targeting MacOS and Linux running Bash and ZSH, what's the correct way to add to the path in an agnostic way? - say for install scripts

Linux has its system profile files as:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/zsh/profile
```

Where MacOS uses:

```
/etc/profile
/etc/zprofile
```

Comment: Usually, the individual user would change their `PATH` variable's value in their personal shell startup files.  I would be concerned if a 3rd-party software changed stuff under `/etc`.

Comment: Avoid etc, make changes to append to files in the user home directory

Comment: Another option (if you're not going to install system-wide into e.g. `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin/`, but say for instance somewhere under `/opt`, would be to create a symlink from you executable  in `/usr/local/bin` ... entirely shell agnostic, even it the user then chose tcsh, fish or whatever ...

Comment: Note that macOS uses the file `/etc/paths` to store the system configuration for the default paths. I would only suggest editing this file as root and only edit it if you intend to apply your defaults to all users.